# Opencart JS Validation on guest checkout

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation, opencart2.x

I have added a few extras fields to guest checkout and some of them need validation. As, HTML input "required" doesn't appear to work in the "panel collapse " environment and the PHP validation is super-cryptic (for me anyway), has anybody used JS validation here.
I have set up JS validation and it does alert when a field is left blank, but on closing the alert box, it moves onto payment_method without forcing a correction in the guest checkout. Before I dive too deep, is it an error in my JS validation, or is it a characteristic of "panel collapse", thereby forcing me to use PHP validation. Opencart v2.3.0.2
This code alerts to an empty field but moves onto payment_method on closing the alert box.

```
<form name="guest_form" >
  <tr>
    <td class="col-md-1">
      <div class="form-group required">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input class="form-control" id="input-payment- 
              city" name="pickup_date" placeholder="**Collection Date" type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="pull-right">
      <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_continue; ?>" id="button-guest" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="guestValid()" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function guestValid()
  {
    var pickup_date = document.forms["guest_form"]["pickup_date"].value;

    if (pickup_date == "")
    {
      window.alert("Please select Collection Date");
      pickup_date.focus();
      return false;
    }
  }

</script>
```

Comment: It's obviously wrong if it's not working how you intend it.  Importantly though so you don't make mistakes EVER, JavaScript is client-side, I could turn that off and enter anything I want remember that, you're not my boss even if you made the site. Protect yourself always from bad input on the server-side (PHP is where you should be validating but for looks, you're decorating the client side of things).

Comment: Can you show me an html form requesting guestValid()?

Comment: I have edited to include a portion of the HTML associated with the JS validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted the problem - The button was executing the validation function and then once the alert box was closed, it then continued with the click #button-guest in checkout.tpl. To resolve this, I put the validation in the checkout.tpl at the beginning of the #button-guest function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the on The controller file `catalog/controller/checkout/guest.php`
define `pickup_date` on controller and add `pickup_date_TEXT_LANGUAGE`  on your language file to translate the value
on `json` code add if statment to valedate the input value

```
if ((utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['pickup_date'])) = '') {
            $json['error']['pickup_date'] = $this->language->get('error_pickup_date_TEXT_LANGUAGE');
        }
```

you have also to define the error MSG `error_pickup_date_TEXT_LANGUAGE` on your languages files